# How to incorporate smart pointers in class member function for real time allocation?

Tags: class, oop, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm creating new object pointers at runtime for N cameras using raw pointers. These pointers are created in a class member function and they each service their own thread - I'm not sure if/how to use smart pointers instead of "new" to allocate the object pointers on the heap. I later delete them in the destructor but I would prefer a cleaner memory management approach than using raw pointers.

Both shared and unique pointer seem to destruct at the end of the scope if initialized in the class member function. I also need to determine the number of cameras at runtime.

Currently:

```
void cameraManager::scanNetwork(){ 
  for(int i=0; i < this->numCameras; ++i){
      auto * cam = new Camera(this->camConfig[i]);
          ....
  }
}
```

Something along these lines:

```
void cameraManager::scanNetwork(){ 
  for(int i=0; i < this->numCameras; ++i){
      std::shared_ptr<Camera> cam = std::make_shared<Camera>(new Camera)(this->camConfig[i]);
          ....
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want these camera pointers to deallocate when the class deallocates - is there a way to "bind" the destructor of a smart pointer to the destructor of another object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to keep the `Camera`s' smart pointers in scope along with the class.

The following attempt from the question has the right idea, but unfortunately `cam` gets created and destroyed on each iteration:

> ```
>   for(int i=0; i < this->numCameras; ++i){
>       std::shared_ptr<Camera> cam = std::make_shared<Camera>(new Camera)(this->camConfig[i]);
>           ....
>   }
> ```

---

The `Camera`s could be kept in scope by keeping the shared pointers in a member vector. This way, when the `cameraManager` goes out of scope the destructors will be called for the cameras:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

struct camConfiguration { };

struct Camera {
    Camera(camConfiguration) {};
};

struct cameraManager {
    int numCameras;
    std::vector<camConfiguration> camConfig;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Camera>> cameras; // will hold the Cameras
    // or, if you only want the cameras to live in the cameraManager, then
    // std::vector<Camera> cameras; // will hold the Cameras without smart pointers

    cameraManager(int numCameras) : numCameras{numCameras}, camConfig(numCameras) {}
    void scanNetwork();
};

void cameraManager::scanNetwork() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numCameras; ++i) {
        // each Camera is added to the cameras vector
        cameras.push_back(std::make_shared<Camera>(this->camConfig[i]));
    }
}

int main()
{
    // will hold the Cameras that must outlive the cameraManager
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Camera>> cameras_to_keep; 

    {
        cameraManager cm{4};
        cm.scanNetwork();

        cameras_to_keep.push_back(cm.cameras[0]);
        cameras_to_keep.push_back(cm.cameras[3]);
    } // shared pointers in cameraManager are destroyed, i.e. Camera 1 & Camera 2 are destroyed

} 
// remaining Cameras in cameras_to_keep are destroyed
```

---

Of course, as mentioned in the comments above, it might be easier, if you only want `Camera`s to exist within the `cameraManager` to simply use a `std::vector` without the `std::shared_ptr`s.